# Check multiple conditions in if statement

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

i have a form to be filled by user, it have a check box to find out if the user account is active, if the checkbox is checked, i want to find out if it has a username and password in the database, if not msgbox should appear. i have one am working on i need to be sure about the if statement... is it correct, if not please explain.

```
      Protected Sub ibtnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ibtnSave.Click
    objBU_Accounts_Contacts = New BU_Accounts_Contacts
    Dim err As Integer
    With objBU_Accounts_Contacts
        .FK_AccountId = AccountID
        .ContactEmail = txtConEmail.Text
        .ContactFax = txtConFax.Text
        .ContactMobile = txtConMobile.Text
        .ContactName = txtContactName.Text
        .ContactTitle = txtContactTitle.Text
        .ContactTelephone = txtConTel.Text
        .PharmaLicNo = ""
        .PharmaExpDate = ""
        .HasCredintials = False

        If chkActive.Checked = True Then
            .IsActive = True
        Else
            .IsActive = False
        End If
        .IsApproved = True
        .IsMainContact = False
        .Password = ""
        .Remarks = txtConRemarks.Text
        .UserName = ""
        .SecurityAnswer = ""
        .SecurityQuestion = ""

        If chkActive.Checked = True AndAlso ((objBU_Accounts_Contacts.UserName) And (objBU_Accounts_Contacts.Password) IsNot Nothing) Then
            err = .Add()
        Else
            MsgBox("E-submission Account Not Created, Plaese Create One First")
        End If

        If ContactID = 0 Then
            err = .Add()
        Else
            .ContactId = ContactID
            err = .Update()
        End If
    End With
    If err = 0 Then
        If SessionVariables.CultureInfo = "en-US" Then
            CtlCommon.ShowMessage(Me.Page, "Saved Successfully")
        Else
            CtlCommon.ShowMessage(Me.Page, "تم الحفظ بنجاح")
        End If
    Else
        If SessionVariables.CultureInfo = "en-US" Then
            CtlCommon.ShowMessage(Me.Page, "Error while saving")
        Else
            CtlCommon.ShowMessage(Me.Page, "خطأ أثناء الحفظ")
        End If
    End If
    FillGrid()
    ClearAll()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you meant, this if statement...

```
If chkActive.Checked = True AndAlso ((objBU_Accounts_Contacts.UserName) And (objBU_Accounts_Contacts.Password) IsNot Nothing) Then
```

You should change to

```
If chkActive.Checked = True AndAlso ((objBU_Accounts_Contacts.UserName IsNot Nothing) And (objBU_Accounts_Contacts.Password IsNot Nothing)) Then
```

I want to say, you can compare one by one object.

Comment: If i were you, I will check **txtUserName.Text** before add to objBU_Accounts_Contacts.

Comment: No,it just complete if statement.
If you want to check Exist Username you should check it with Database or what your saved accounts.

Comment: could you add it to your answer... and thank you you have been helpful